# If cell contains this text return that cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Look at the example I have below.

```
A-.375-VG-M761   
A-.375-VG-O630  
A-.375-VG-O780   
A-.75-VG-602     
A-.75-VG-603     
A-.75-VG-604
```

In one column I have two "SKUs": *A-.375-VG* and *A-.75-VG*.
I want to use this data to separate these SKUs onto two specific tabs of the same sheet.
How do I search through a column and return a cell if it contains a certain string of text?

I've tried REGEXMATCH and FIND but neither of those seem to do the trick.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Assuming your data is in column  `Z` and cells 10-17).*

Use this formula for A-.375-VG in one tab:

```
=QUERY(Z10:Z17,"SELECT Z where Z like 'A-.375-VG%' ")
```

and for A-.75-VG in the other

```
=QUERY(Z10:Z17,"SELECT Z where Z like 'A-.75-VG%' ")
```

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en-GB)

Comment: Thank you, as a new comer to all of this there seems to be a ton to sort through for functions. This worked perfectly

Comment: My pleasure. Glad it worked out.